# Lost some data (specifically my voice recordings

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, backup, data-recovery

My phone started acting really weirdly lately. It would shut off by itself and turn on again, and sometimes when it just turned on, it would turn off again. The home screen would freeze, and I couldn't do anything. So I backed up everything onto my computer, and I reset my phone. Suprisingly, my phone went back to normal! So I tried moving everything back onto my phone. lost a lot of my photos and music, but it wasn't a big deal. What I'm upset about is that when I moved all of the voice recordings onto the computer, everything was there. But transferring back into my phone, I lost a few voice recordings, especially this one voice recording that is very important to me. I can't find it in its app folder, and can't find it anywhere. I looked in media, music, sub media, videos, everything I could think of yet I can't find it! Is it possible to get it back somehow?? Or do you know where the voice recording could be(stored) ? Please help!

My phone is a samsung google galaxy nexus version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what application you record your voice with. But maybe it save the voices in a folder which is hidden. (the folders which have dots at the first of their names.)

Comment: ohh i see thanks. So I just have to check through all of the folders for hidden ones?? I looked through most of them, and there is no folder with a dot at the first of their names. and other folders say that theyre 'empty'. any other ideas??

Comment: you didn't say what is your application.

Comment: An app called Smartvoice recorder

Comment: I check this app, actually it makes a simple visible folder named "SmartVoiceRecorder" !!!

Comment: Yes, i know! But like, its not there.... I had three recordings, and only one is in the folder, when i made sure that i copied everything.